# change size of bootstrap pop up

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am not sure where I can edit the bootstrap modal pop-up on my portfolio? It is the chili picture in the bottom on this site. At the moment it shows in 1000*600px, but I would like it bigger.

[Link to my portfolio](https://vouzalis.com/courses/AU/visualisering-og-projektkommunikation.php)

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <article class="block-thumbnail">
                    <div class="block-image">
                        <div class="overlay"></div>
                        <img
                            class="coursepic"   
                            src="/images/thumbs/image1.jpg" 
                            data-toggle="modal" 
                            data-target="#myModal1" 
                            alt="Trolltunga, Norway"
                        >   
                    </div>
                <div class="block-data">
                    <h3>
                        Test
                    </h3>
                </div>
            </article>
        </div>
```

**CSS**

```
img.coursepic {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
img.coursepic:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0.5;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    border-radius: 2px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

**JS**

```
function centerModal() {
    $(this).css('display', 'block');
    var $dialog = $(this).find(".modal-dialog");
    var offset = ($(window).height() - $dialog.height()) / 2;
    // Center modal vertically in window
    $dialog.css("margin-top", offset);
}

$('.modal').on('show.bs.modal', centerModal);
$(window).on("resize", function () {
    $('.modal:visible').each(centerModal);
});
```

Comment: The way you are calling the modal to open is different to how I would recommend - If you are using "data-target" you shouldn't also need to trigger it via JavaScript - See here http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-usage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its working fine with `modal-lg`

add this snippet in your `centerModal()`

```
$dialog.addClass("modal-lg");
```

[image]

Comment: @KrMa Your Welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

for `data-target="#myModal1"`, the `#myModel1` should get `modal-lg` class

and add `class="coursepic modal-lg"`

or use this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Large Modal</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
   <img class="coursepic" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
 

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
       
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
         
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
           <img class="coursepic" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
        </div>
       
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I now tried to add modal-lg, but it is still the same size :-/

Comment: @KrMa you have to add `modal-lg` class to the div that has `modal-dialog` class.

Comment: ah okay. I do not have any class at the moment that is modal-dialog :-/ I will try to add modal-dialog modal-lg to a div now

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap does have some built in styles to create modals of different sizes:

The important class here is **modal-lg**

```html
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>This is a large modal.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello. THank you for your answer. I tried to set the modal-lg on the pictures, and the different div. But it does not change the size of the modal.